# rsync delete files on sending side after transfer

Tags: rsync

I want to download a large amount of data from a remote machine.
I'd like the data to be erased on the remote machine everytime a file finishes downloading.

How do I do that? Is there a flag for rsync to do this?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You need to pass the `--remove-source-files` option to the `rsync` command. It tells `rsync` to remove from the sending side the files (meaning non-directories) that are a part of the transfer and have been successfully duplicated on the receiving side. Do not pass the `--delete` option to `rsync` command as it delete extraneous files from destination directory.
Delete source after successful transfer using `rsync`.

The syntax is:

```
rsync --remove-source-files -options /path/to/src/ /path/to/dest
rsync --remove-source-files -options /path/to/src/ computerB:/path/to/dest
rsync --remove-source-files -av /path/to/src/*.avi computerB:/path/to/dest
```

Reference : http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-appleosx-rsync-delete-file-after-transfer/

Comment: Is there a way to also delete directories from the source side?

Comment: This is helpful too: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=rsync+--dry-run+--remove-source-files+-avzPh

Comment: explainshell.com is a beautifully-done tool, thanks for that tip.

Comment: See also this very helpful post on Unix StackExchange about removing directories as well: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371144/usage-of-remove-source-files-option-of-rsync

Comment: Is there a way to **always** delete source files i.e. even when their transfer to destination fails?

Comment: rsync is for actions related to duplication/mirroring being successful.  If you want to purge any remaining after the rsync job is done, that is a job for basic rm.